# Get value of element found inside another element(multiple classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to retrieve the value of an input field of class `anotherClass` through jquery selectors. However I get an empty result. Below is different methods I used to get this value but to no avail I get the desired result.  There are many input fields with that class but what makes the `input` unique is the `label` wrapped around it. How could I retrieve the result of the input field shown below?

HTML

```
<label class="class1 class2 class3" data-reactid=".0.1">
    <input class="anotherClass" type="text" data-reactid=".0.1.0" value="XXXXXXX" >
</label>
```

Jquery

```
function getValue() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('.class1 .class2 .class3 input');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(element, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('value');
    });
}
```

Comment: You are not using jQuery on this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need space between classes as space mean you are going for *descendant*. You can combine multiple class with *dot* or *comma*.

```
 var element = document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2.class3 input');
```

Or using comma

```
 var element = document.querySelectorAll('.class1,class2,class3 input');
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of your selectors the same way you would as if you were writing CSS:

```
var element = $('.class1.class2.class3 input');
```

Answer (score 0):

With your html above, it should be as simple as

```
$('.anotherClass').val();
```

If you want to search from the parent, using their classes, you can do

```
$('.class1.class2.class3 .anotherClass').val();
```

```js
document.write($('.class1.class2.class3 .anotherClass').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="class1 class2 class3" data-reactid=".0.1">
  <input class="anotherClass" type="text" data-reactid=".0.1.0" value="XXXXXXX">
</label>
```